# Error building docker image with Dockerfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, github, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

I’m trying to build docker image with a configuration in `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER axiom88guru(axiom88guru@gmail.com)
Configuration for app below.
Run upgrades

RUN apt-get update
Install basic packages

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
Install Ruby

RUN apt-get -qq -y install ruby-full
RUN gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
RUN gem install foreman
Install rails-new-docker

WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://github.com/axiom88-guru/rails-docker.git /app
RUN bundle install --without development test
Run rails-new-docker

ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE dockerkeybase
ENV RAILS_ENV production
EXPOSE 5959
CMD foreman start -f Procfile
```

When I run these commands in bash they work as expected, but not during docker build:

> ```
> Removing intermediate container 344e99851852
> Step 8/14 : WORKDIR /app
> —> 3c204a395f23
> Removing intermediate container 680b1841a3fc
> Step 9/14 : RUN git clone https://github.com/axiom88-guru/rails-docker.git /app
> —> Running in d7a9de9f6ab5
> /bin/sh: 1: git: not found
> The command ‘/bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/axiom88-guru/rails-docker.git /app’ returned a non-zero code: 127
> ```

Could anyone help me find out the solution please?

Comment: you need to install `git`, its not provided in the base `ubuntu` image

Comment: i am using ubuntu16.0.4 and it supports git :)

Comment: `docker run ubuntu:16.04 sh -c git` will give you the same error because it is not installed in the provided `ubuntu` image. You have to `apt-get install git` for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to have git installed since the base `ubuntu` image provides only a minimal set of installed packages (this is done to keep image size small).

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER axiom88guru(axiom88guru@gmail.com)
# Configuration for app below.
# Run upgrades

RUN apt-get update
# Install basic packages

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs git
# Install Ruby

RUN apt-get -qq -y install ruby-full
RUN gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
RUN gem install foreman
# Install rails-new-docker

WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://github.com/axiom88-guru/rails-docker.git /app
RUN bundle install --without development test
# Run rails-new-docker

ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE dockerkeybase
ENV RAILS_ENV production
EXPOSE 5959
CMD foreman start -f Procfile
```

This version should work. I just added `git` to the first `apt-get install` step.

Comment: It was a nice trick. I even didn't know ubuntu image from docker doesn't provide git. Thanks a lot, you saved my time:)